# InfoPath form closes and redirects to deleted SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

When a user clicks submit for the first time, the form closes and they are redirected to an old library that I deleted. But if they were to go back and edit their form then submit again, it will redirect to the correct library. Why does it redirect to the old library, and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

did you ever checked URL for the InfoPath form (if you are using externally the link for submission form). If so please do ckeck parameters in the URL with name "Source="

(OR) once you open the submission form, copy the url from the browser and paste it in any notepad, do check the passed parameter(s). some parameters are as below:

```
XsnLocation=

SaveLocation=

Source=

DefaultItemOpen=
```